# Laravel order two columns from lower to higher

Tags: laravel

I have the following table structure;
orders:

```
 id, user_id, from_time, to_time, product_id, quantity, price, created_at, updated_at
```

So to say I have 3 orders with the following data:

```
user_id: 1,
from_time: 10:00,
to_time: 11:00

user_id: 2,
from_time: 12:00,
to_time: 15:00

user_id: 3,
from_time: 11:00,
to_time: 12:00
```

my goal is to fetch all orders and arrange them so the `from_time` and `to_time` are also in an `ascending order`, in my case the order would be `1, 3, 2.`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `orderBy()` query method?

```php
Foo::orderBy('from_time', 'asc')->orderBy('to_time', 'asc');
```